# how to loop text to speech in android studio

Tags: android, media-player, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

How can I loop the sounds of the text to speech? I've tried to synthesize the TTS but it gives me error in the synthesis.

I want to put it to the media player because it has looping method.

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap();
        String textToConvert = "welcome to the center";
        String exStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File appTmpPath = new File(exStoragePath);
        final String destinationFileName = appTmpPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "test.wav";
        myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, textToConvert);
        mtts.synthesizeToFile(textToConvert, myHashRender, destinationFileName); //error in here
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "audio saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(destinationFileName);
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_image_play);
    }
});
```

and this the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.synthesizeToFile(java.lang.String, java.util.HashMap, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.activity.Main.quiz$4.onClick(quiz.java:209)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5246)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21256)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: There are many problems going on at the same time here... and many questions left unanswered.  Is the tts initialized?  Are you handling the fact that synthesizeToFile is an asynchronous method?  What is the actual error you're getting?  Are you sending the correct parameters to synthesizeToFile?  ... and without all the code, it's impossible for anyone to answer for sure.  So if you include all the Activity code, or at least a "minimum runnable example," then you might get help.  It looks like you coded too many lines at the same time without testing them.

Comment: i already tested my code using synthesizetofile but seems that the synthesizetofile is deprecated to api 21 and the error is inside to my imagebutton and pointing out to the synthesize and gives a null object reference. see my updated post

Comment: That error means that the mtts object is null at the time you attempt to "invoke" the method mtts.synthesizetofile on it -- it is not initialized.  Even if you fix this, you're still going to have more problems (because the synthesize to file is asynchronous and your are expecting an immediate result).  I suggest breaking your projecting smaller parts and verify each step works before moving on to the next: 1) make a program that *only* successfully synthesizes to a file. 2) add an UtteranceProgressListener to this so you can tell when the synthesizetofile is complete.  3) add the looping.